# Join n elements after an element in a list with the list itself

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using PySpark.

**Follow up**: I think I only need to know how to select `n` elements after an element in a list, and join them with the list itself.

For example,  you have a list 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'

```
+-------+-----+
| _index| item|
+-------+-----+
|   0   |   a |
|   1   |   b |
|   2   |   c |
|   3   |   d |
|   4   |   e |
|   5   |   f |
|   6   |   g |
+-------+-----+
```

of index 0 to 6; and we want to join, say `n=3` elements after 'c', with the list itself, and we get

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| _index | item1 | item2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|   3    |   d   |   d   |
|   4    |   e   |   e   |
|   5    |   f   |   f   |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

**The following is one piece of related code.** Is it possible to modify this code to pick elements after `A` within a distance `n` and join them with the list that contains `A`? I am new to spark I would like some help! Thanks!

---

Suppose we have many lists. We first find an element in these lists with some condition `condition1`. Give it alias `A`.

If we randomly pick another element after `A`'s index (within certain index distance, say `1-3`), and then join it with the list that contains `A`, then we can do the following.

```
df.where(
    (col('condition1')==0) # finds an element satisfying some condition, name it as 'A'
).alias('A').join(
    df.alias('B'), 
    # randomly pick another element after 'A' within index distance 1 to 3
    # and join it with the list that contains 'A'
    ((col('A.ListId')==col('B.ListId')) & (random.randint(1,4)+col('A._index'))==col('B._index'))
)
```

Comment: This is all very abstract- it would be helpful if you could provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) with small representative input DataFrame and the desired output.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for possible workaround that you could apply:

```
l = [(0,"a"), (1,"b"), (2,"c"), (3,"d"), (4,"e"), (5,"f"), (6,"g")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, schema=["_index", "item"])

# just get the value out of the row
start = df.filter(df.item == "c").select("_index").first()[0]
df.filter((df._index > start) & (df._index <= random.randint(start + 1, start + 4))).show()
```

So I think the only part was missing, apart from your join, was getting the integer from A's index.